# iOS problem with tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath not firing window

Tags: ios, uitableview, webview

first time, please be gentle...

I've an iOS app; a tabbed RSS reader, each tab has a different navigation view of various RSS feeds. All is well, until you select the row to view the feed, when nothing happens. Code I'm using is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (_webViewController == nil) {
        self.webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    }
    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _webViewController.entry = entry;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Where RSSEntry is a class which just sets the variables for the RSS feed. I've set up a WebViewController.xib, m and h to hold the view.

When you select the row, nothing happens. Any ideas gratefully accepted.

thanks

Rob

Comment: Did you check if really nothing happens by putting a breakpoint for example?

Comment: Valentin - sorry, I missed your comment before, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does self.navigationController evaluate to non-nil? In some cases the property navigationController may not point to your enclosing UINavigationController. I've seen this with special view controller hierarchies...

Comment: Thanks nielsbot. How would I fix this? My brain has died today...;)

Comment: What's your view controller hierarchy look like?

Comment: TabView is the main view controller, then with 2 navigation views on two tabs

Comment: Is your table view controller directly on a UINavigationController view stack?

Comment: My main view controller has two tabs within the tabcontroller, which call seperate nibs for each. Each one of those nibs is a table view. I'm beginning to think here that I should put each table view within a nav controller..?

Comment: yes you must! the navigationController property returns the nearest enclosing UINavigationController. If you don't have an enclosing UINavigationController the navigationController property will return nil. Without a navigation controller, there won't be any navigation!

Comment: Yes, I really should have thought that one through! Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Argh, though now I've done that it's still not working. Time for rest, look at it tomorrow Rob... ;) Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

`_webViewController` has likely been released when you go to use it, because you've allocated it within the `if` block. At the end of that block, it is autoreleased.

Remove the `autorelease` clause in your alloc statement for WebViewController, and add `[webViewController release]` after your call to pushViewController.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Tried this but unfortunately the same effect; no response on the link.

Comment: Oh! I missed this before. You are creating `self.webViewController` but then using `_webViewController`. Notice the leading underscore in the latter. Could that be the problem? I suspect the autorelease thing is an issue as well, fwiw.

Comment: Hi Mark - no, not that either, but thanks for looking at this I appreciate your help! I must be missing something completely obvious somewhere...

Comment: What do you see as you step thru this code in the debugger? Any of these variables nil when you expect otherwise?

Comment: Not that I can see Mark, it seems fine. It's picking up the article URL fine from the array, for instance

Comment: Try passing `nil` for bundle in the initWithNibName call. Shouldn't make a difference, but you never know. (I never pass anything other than nil, fwiw.)

Comment: No change :( Thanks for sticking with this by the way, it's been killing me!

Comment: Do I assume correctly that you have synthesized webViewController as _webViewController? I suppose if you hadn't you'd get a compilation error... Is self.navigationController nil?

Comment: Yes to the synthesize. That could be it with the self.navigationController, as I've the Nav view inside a Tab view; maybe there's some confusion there. Going slightly cross-eyed with this now.

Comment: Yes, it is nil Mark, nice one. Not sure how to fix this at the moment though, but explains why it's not working.